# Is it okay to rewrite unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing

I am still learning OOP, and each day I discover something foreign. So when writing unit tests, it looks like it's common to have function names, and the program design in general, already defined. "Test this *factory* or that *dependency container* to see if it works as expected", for example.

Being a learner, I am pretty sure I'd want to change a lot of things, from function names to the structure of the code to what the functions do themselves, over time. Obviously, this would mean rewriting the tests to make them pass. Did you face this problem? A few things I read speak like it is taboo to touch tests once written, so how do you solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it is taboo to touch tests once written

This is total nonsense, of course. Time passes, things change, code evolves, tests need to be touched. Feel free to amend and rewrite tests, but be careful to not accidentally lose functionality in the process (when rewritten version does not test cases that previous version did).

For me this problem simply doesn't exist.

Comment: So as long as I ensure 'coverage' is 100%, I can keep rewriting tests to better define how my code should work? That sounds so perfect.

Comment: Keeping coverage at 100% is hard and not always practical. In my projects it's usually around 92-97%. Feel free to rewrite the tests, but be careful to not accidentally lose functionality in the process (when rewritten version does not test cases that previous version did).

Answer (score 3):

An important thing to remember is that test code is just as important as production code, if it's not, why bother with it at all? With this in mind, it's just as important to maintain and refactor your tests as it is to maintain and refactor your production code.

That said, I wouldn't recommend rewriting a test just because your knowledge has moved forward and you don't like the way you did it initially. If a test is testing something worthwhile, is understandable, and always passes, i'd leave it alone.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sergio said, of course you have to change tests if the class under test changes.

Just to note about changing tests in general: don't forget to make sure that the new test actually *fails* if the class under test is wrong. When you're doing new code and writing tests first, you get to see the test fail before you implement the new functionality and the test passes (TDD's "red/green" rhythm). When you're changing tests, you need to make sure you didn't just make a test that always passes.

For your question about changing things about the class under test (names, behaviour), you can easily do this in a test-first manner too:

1. Change the test to reflect the changes you would like to make to the class under test
2. Run the test to verify that it fails (or possibly won't compile, if name changes) [Red]
3. Update the class and see the test pass [Green]

Answer (score 1):

I think this depens on your programm. If you have a really huge programm you should not rewrite your tests if you are not sure that other functions uses that functions. If you are in the development you can change them if you are sure that this will make no trouble.

Comment: It does not depend on size of codebase, IMHO. If he changes too much, he'll have broken tests. You don't commit code when tests are red. But if you do, then you probably don't need tests at all.